# Why don't these external flashes fire when the camera shoots in Live View mode?

Tags: flash, troubleshooting

I had the opportunity to use some professional flashes yesterday and I found out that **they didn't fire** when I was trying to shoot with the camera in Live View mode.

The flashes were two **Elinchrom FX400**, one wirelessly synchronized with the camera and the other was activated automatically when the first one fired (With a photocell or something).

Using the camera normally fired both flashes at the same time with no issues, but live view mode deactivated both. Why the LV mode is incompatible? Am I missing something?

By the way, I tried this with two cameras, **a Canon 1000D and a 550D**.

Comment: How are you controlling the flashes?  What wireless controller is being used?

Comment: @ahockley Uhmmm, not remember, just a very long cable connected to the flash with a black box in the top of it and a remote trigger in the hotshoe of the camera. I think it was generic. But it worked perfectly in non-lv modes!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like when using a non-Canon flash you can't fire the flash while in live view with a Silent Shooting mode enabled, says the manual:

- If you use flash, the [Disable] operation will take effect even if you had set it to [Mode 1] or [Mode 2].
- When using a non-Canon flash unit, set it to [Disable]. (The flash will not fire if [Mode 1] or [Mode 2] is set.)

from http://martybugs.net/blog/blog.cgi/gear/lights/Triggering-Flashes-While-Using-LiveView.html

Answer (score 1):

I found out yes you can. Put the camera into multiple frame/burst mode. With your remote take 2 frames, the second frame will activate the flash... it took me AGES to find out how this worked but it does

Answer (score 1):

I tried the method put forward by George, "Put the camera into multiple frame/burst mode", This will not work on my Canon 760D so my best suggestion would be to turn off live view before shooting, this is the simplest method to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around. I set my external flash to channel one I set my on camera flash channel one and have it so it triggers my external flash then I cover up the light on the camera flash and it will trigger the only other light available the external flash when doing it this way and the flash is popped up I can use live view and trigger The flash